# Is it possible to call a fragment from a fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments

I believe the answer is yes..Not sure FragmentManager applies here..because one fragment contains a ListView and the other contains different widgets(ImageView, Text)

within my Main Activity i call my 1st fragment using :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LFragment lFragment=    (LFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lFragment");
    if(lFragment==null){
        lFragment= new LFragment();
        FragmentTransaction  transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content,lFragment,"lFragment");
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Okay so once I am in my LFragment(1st Fragment) class i use this method to go to the next Fragment:

```
//handling item click
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
    ViewGroup viewGroup=(ViewGroup)view;
    TextView txt=(TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    int itemPosition = position;
    //stores the text of the clicked item in the list
    String value = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //using intent to get into infoFragment
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),infoFragment.class);
    //store string value into intent
    intent.putExtra(value,itemPosition);

    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    //kills the fragment
    getActivity().finish();
```

This is what I have tried using(2nd Fragment)..but getIntent does not work

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    RatingBar rating=(RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    TextView degrees=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    //ERROR "can not resolve method getIntent"
    Intent intent = getIntent();
}
```

Comment: I suggest using an interface and pass your data through there so the activity handles the fragment replacement.

Comment: Would you happen to have a reference I could look at please?  Also would that mean I would have to change how i call my 1st fragment in the Main Activity or just the onClickList method?

Comment: @Raykud  Thanks i see what u mean now

Comment: Did you solve the problem - if so close the question out. If not, let us know for further help.

Comment: @Kalininskaya  Raykud answer helped..using interfaces   not the answer provided below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...

```html
LFragment fragment = new LFragment();
FragmentManager FM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  FM.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```